# Can you configure Compass to delete unwanted development files, i.e. sourcemaps?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I have a pretty straightforward Compass configuration that handles both development and production code quite neatly:

```
http_path = "/"
sass_dir = "assets/scss"
css_dir = "assets/css"
images_dir = "assets/img"
javascripts_dir = "assets/js"

# Reflective command line configuration switches; invoke with: compass compile --environment=production
output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded

# Additional Sass configuration
Sass::Script::Number.precision = 3
sourcemaps_required = (environment == :production) ? false : true
sass_options = {:sourcemap => sourcemaps_required}
enable_sourcemaps = sourcemaps_required
```

The `sourcemaps_required` flag determines whether or not to output sourcemaps based on the current Compass `environment` switch at compilation time.

To make this complete, I'd like to add a further instruction that could delete any sourcemaps in `assets/css` when `sourcemaps_required` evaluates as **false** – i.e. when outputting minified CSS for deployment using the `--environment=production` Compass flag.

Is this sort of file cleanup instruction possible within the same Compass config file, or do I need to call a separate script?

*(At the moment, I'm just deleting unwanted .map files by hand before upload.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
on_sourcemap_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
     File.delete filename
  end
end
```

You only need to specify under which circumstances this must be executed (on prod.)

Hope it helps : )

Comment: This looks perfect, thank you, but unfortunately I'm getting an error upon execution: http://pastebin.com/MeyD7Kkn

Comment: We are using sourcemaps for work.We debug our code right on chrome, with livereload.I really cannot understand why you want that behave. Can you tell me which kind of app. are you using, any framework, how you do the deployments and if you are using any repository for the deployments ?

We use capistrano, which takes the code from github, and we have the .maps ignores, so we dont add this to production. Also, assetics does all assets compression for us, so we just send a non minified version, but assetics takes care for us. If you give me those data, I think I can help you.